# Connect PHP 5.4 to MSSQL 2012 ODBC

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

I have tried to connect to a local MSSQL database now using mutliple methods and each time I receive an error. Please could someone help, I have the connection used below along with the corresponding error message. Thanks

PHP Version 5.4.17 nts VC9

Windows 7, UAC off, Firewall disabled, Run in a command window using Administrator

MS SQL 2012

Windows ODBC Drivers

- SQL Server
- SQL Server Native Client 11.0

**phpinfo**

```
odbc

ODBC Support => enabled
Active Persistent Links => 0
Active Links => 0
ODBC library => Win32

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
odbc.allow_persistent => On => On
odbc.check_persistent => On => On
odbc.default_cursortype => Static cursor => Static cursor
odbc.default_db => no value => no value
odbc.default_pw => no value => no value
odbc.default_user => no value => no value
odbc.defaultbinmode => return as is => return as is
odbc.defaultlrl => return up to 4096 bytes => return up to 4096 bytes
odbc.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
odbc.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited

PDO

PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => odbc

PDO_ODBC

PDO Driver for ODBC (Win32) => enabled
ODBC Connection Pooling => Enabled, strict matching
```

--

```
odbc_connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='127.0.0.1';Port=1433;DATABASE=[database]","[sql_user]","[sql_pass]);
```

> Warning:  odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied., SQL
>   state 08001 in SQLConnect in C:\source.php on line 2

```
odbc_connect("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER='127.0.0.1;Port=1433';DATABASE=[database]","[sql_user]","[sql_pass]");
```

> Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native
>   Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL
>   Server [53]. , SQL state 08001 in SQLConnect in C:\source.php on line
>   3

```
odbc_connect("DRIVER={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};SERVER='127.0.0.1';Port=1433;Integrated Security=SSPI","","");
```

> Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]
>   Data source name not found and no default driver specified, SQL state
>   IM002 in SQLConnect in C:\source.php on line 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to mssql using PDO like this:

```
$dbh = new PDO('odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=127.0.0.1;Database=DatabaseName; Uid=User;Pwd=Password');
// use the connection here


// and now we're done; close it
$dbh = null;
```

Just make sure to provide the correct user and password for the database connection.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in C:\source.php:2
Stack trace:
#0 C:\source.php(2): PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:Server=l...', '[sql_user]',
 '[sql_pass]')
#1 {main}
  thrown in C:\source.php on line 2

Comment: Have you enabled the PDO mssql extension in your php.ini file? I've edited my answer try it with the new connection string.